# Touch and Drag Sprite in Andengine

Tags: andengine

I'm trying to make a sprite so when you touch it and drag your finger, the sprite follows your movement.  I've tried to follow the AndEngine examples, but they are part of GLES1.  I'm using GLES2.

Within my code, the onAreaTouched is being called, but it is not continuously being called to update the sprite with my finger.

Thanks in advance.

```
public class RectangleFactory extends Sprite {

public float randomNumber;

public RectangleFactory(float pX, float pY, ITextureRegion pTextureRegion,
        VertexBufferObjectManager pVertexBufferObjectManager) {
    super(pX, pY, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObjectManager);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    Random random = new Random();
    randomNumber = (float) random.nextInt(BallShakeActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH);

};

@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, float X, float Y)
{
    Log.d("Mark", "circles are touched");
    this.setPosition(pSceneTouchEvent.getX() - this.getWidth() / 2, pSceneTouchEvent.getY() - this.getHeight() / 2);

    if(pSceneTouchEvent.isActionMove()){
        Log.d("Mark", "finger is moving");
    }       

    return true;
    };


@Override
protected void onManagedUpdate(final float pSecondsElapsed){

    if(this.mY > 0f){       

    }
    else{
        Random random = new Random();
        randomNumber = (float) random.nextInt(BallShakeActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH);
        this.setPosition(randomNumber, 800f);
    }

    super.onManagedUpdate(pSecondsElapsed);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find some examples, including a touch-drag example, for `AndEngine GLES2` in the `AndEngineExamples` repository on Nicolas' Github page.
https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples

The examples seem to be mostly for the `GLES2` branch but there may also be some examples for the `GLES2-AnchorCenter` branch as well.

Some of the code works with `GLES1`/`master` branch but you're mostly on your own for examples for that branch.